# Using face api js to upload mask on face, I find the face landmarks and append the mask on them but how do I download the appended image as a whole?

Tags: javascript, html, css

relevant HTML

```
<p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile()" style="display: none;"></p>
<p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
<p><img id="output"/></p>

<div class="grid-item"></
     <script src="face-api.min.js"></script>
     <script src="./file.js"></script>
</div>
```

JS (file.js)

This is where I load the image, the models and create the canvas

```
  var image = document.getElementById('output');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models');
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(image);
```

This is how I place the mask on the face.

```
  const item = document.querySelector(".grid-item")

  const overlay = document.createElement("img")
  overlay.src = "./mask.png"
  overlay.alt = "mask overlay."
  overlay.id = "mask"
  overlay.style.cssText = `
    position: absolute;
    left: ${newOffsetLeft}px;
    top: ${newOffsetTop+50}px;
    width: ${eyedist/mask_by_eye}px;
    transform: rotate(${angleEyes}deg);
    z-index:1;
  `

  item.appendChild(overlay);
```

How do I download the appended picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t combine them if the overlay is an img tag. However, if you can load it into the same canvas as the face is being drawn on, you should be able to get the combined image data.